# difference between the result of the sum in the always block and combinational module

Tags: verilog

I am trying design to a pipe lined and a module with resource sharing for comparing the amount of used resource in synthesize.the pipe line work well but i have problem with resource sharing. in the code below in the state s3,s4,s5,s6 the  As,Bs,Cs,Ds,Es registers will be add and the result will be in register fx. in the same states the result of combinational adder module will be store in the register test. but the values are different and i cant figure it out why.
what i am trying to do is solve a differential equation. i avoid multipication in constants by add and shift operation and used a cordic for exponantial part of de.
sorry for bad English and thank you in advance;

```
module topmodule (clk,v1,v2,one,zero,clk_data);
input clk;
output one,zero,clk_data;
output  reg signed [41:0] v1;
output  reg signed [41:0] v2;
parameter [41:0]  el    = - 42'b000000000000100011010011001000000000000000;  
parameter [41:0]  vt    = - 42'b000000000000011001001100110000000000000000;  
parameter [41:0]  I0    =   42'b000000000110010000000000000000000000000000; 
parameter [41:0]  b     =   42'b000000000000101000000000000000000000000000; 
parameter [41:0]  xin   = - 42'b000000000000011111000000000000000000000000; 
parameter [41:0]  yin   =   42'b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000; 
parameter [41:0]  zeroa =   42'b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
parameter [41:0]  onea  =   42'b000000000000000000100000000000000000000000; 
parameter [41:0]  xr    = - 42'b000000000000010111010110011000000000000000; 
reg signed [10:0]  roundint   =   7'b0000000;
reg signed [10:0]  iek   =   7'b0000001;
reg signed [41:0] x;
reg signed [41:0] y;
reg signed [41:0] fx;
reg signed [41:0] shifted2;
reg signed [41:0] xminusel;
reg signed [41:0] xminusvt;
reg signed [41:0] xminusvtdelta;
reg signed [41:0] dx;
reg signed [41:0] dy;
reg signed [41:0] dxdt;
reg signed [41:0] dydt;
reg signed [41:0] z;
reg signed [41:0] intx;
reg signed [41:0] absx;
reg signed [41:0] As;
reg signed [41:0] Bs;
reg signed [41:0] Cs;
reg signed [41:0] Ds;
reg signed [41:0] Es;
reg signed [41:0] Fsx;
reg signed [41:0] test;
wire signed [41:0] Asw;
wire signed [41:0] Bsw;
wire signed [41:0] Csw;
wire signed [41:0] Dsw;
wire signed [41:0] Esw;
wire signed [41:0] fxw;
   wire [3:0] p_s;
   reg [3:0] n_s=4'b0000;  
   parameter s0 =4'b0000; 
   parameter s1 =4'b0001;
   parameter s2 =4'b0010;
   parameter s3 =4'b0011;
   parameter s4 =4'b0100;
   parameter s5 =4'b0101;
   parameter s6 =4'b0110;
   parameter s7 =4'b0111;
   parameter s8 =4'b1000;
   parameter s9 =4'b1001;
   parameter s10=4'b1010;
   parameter s11=4'b1011;
   parameter s12=4'b1100;
   parameter s13loop=4'b1101;
ADD A1(.fxw(fxw),.As(As),.Bs(Bs),.Cs(Cs),.Ds(Ds),.Es(Es));
  assign p_s=n_s;
  assign zero=1'b0;
  assign one=1'b1;
  assign clk_data=clk;
always @(posedge clk)
begin
  case (p_s)
       s0:
       begin
       x=xin;
       y=yin;
     n_s<=s1;
       end
    s1:
       begin
       shifted2=onea;
       fx=onea;
       iek   =   7'b0000000;
       xminusvt=x-vt;
       xminusvtdelta={xminusvt>>>1} ;
       n_s<=s2;
       if (xminusvtdelta<0)
         begin
           absx=~xminusvtdelta;
           absx=absx+1;
         end
       else
         begin
           absx=xminusvtdelta;
         end
       end
       s2:
       begin
      intx={12'b000000000000,absx[30:18],17'b00000000000000000};
       roundint=absx[30:24];
       if(xminusvtdelta<=0)
       begin
       z=xminusvtdelta+ intx;
       end
     else
       begin
       z=xminusvtdelta- intx;
     end
       shifted2=shifted2>>>1;
       n_s<=s3;
       end
     s3:
       begin
        if ( shifted2 < z )
          begin
        z=z-shifted2;
        As=fx;
        Bs={fx>>>1};
        Cs={fx>>>3};
        Ds={fx>>>6};
        Es={fx>>>7};
        fx=As+Bs+Cs+Ds+Es;
     Fsx=fx;
     test<=fxw; 
    end
      shifted2=shifted2>>>1;      
       n_s<=4;
       end
       s4:
       begin
        if ( shifted2 < z )
          begin  
        z=z-shifted2;

            As=fx;
        Bs={fx>>>2};
        Cs={fx>>>5};
        Ds={fx>>>9};
        Es=0;
        fx=As+Bs+Cs+Ds+Es;  
              Fsx=fx;
              test<=fxw;
    end
       shifted2=shifted2>>>1;      
       n_s<=s5;
       end
       s5:
       begin
        if ( shifted2 < z )
          begin
        z=z-shifted2;
            As=fx;
        Bs={fx>>>3};
        Cs={fx>>>7};
        Ds=0;
        Es=0;
        fx=As+Bs+Cs+Ds+Es;
               Fsx=fx;
               test<=fxw;     
    end
       shifted2=shifted2>>>1;       
       n_s<=s6;
       end
     s6:
       begin
        if ( shifted2 < z )
          begin
        z=z-shifted2;
                As=fx;
        Bs={fx>>>4};
        Cs={fx>>>9};
        Ds=0;
        Es=0;
        fx=As+Bs+Cs+Ds+Es;
        test<=fxw;
                Fsx=fx;
    end
       shifted2=shifted2>>>1;

       n_s<=s8;
       end
       s8:
       begin
          if(iek<=roundint)
          begin
            n_s<=s13loop;        
             end
            else
              begin

                n_s<=s9;
         end  
         xminusel=x-el;

       end       
         s13loop:
         begin
iek=iek+1;
 if(xminusvtdelta>0)
                begin
        fx={ fx >>>10}+{fx>>>9}+{fx>>>8}+{fx>>>7}+{fx>>>6}+{fx>>>4}+{fx>>>3}+{fx>>>1}+{fx<<<1} ;
          end
        else
        begin 
         fx={ fx  >>>7}+{ fx  >>>6}+{ fx  >>>5}+{ fx  >>>4}+{ fx  >>>2} ; 
         end         
 n_s<=s8;        
nd

       s9:
       begin
     dx=-{ xminusel>>>5}-{xminusel>>>4}-{xminusel>>>3}-{xminusel>>>2}+{fx>>>4}+{fx>>>3}+{fx>>>2}+{ fx  >>>1}  +{ I0  >>>6} -{ y  >>>6}  ; 
      dy={xminusel<<<2}-{y}; 
       n_s<=s10;
       end

       s10:
       begin
       dxdt={dx>>>15}+{dx>>>13}+{dx>>>12}+{dx>>>11}+{dx>>>10}+{dx>>>9} ; 
       dydt={dy >>>15}+{dy>>>14};       
       n_s<=s11;
       end
       s11:
       begin
      x=x+dxdt;
      y=y+dydt;
       n_s<=s12;
       end
       s12:
       begin
       if (x>=0)
       begin
       x=xr;
       y=y+b;
       end
       v1=x;
       v2=y;
       n_s<=s1;
       end
 endcase
   end
 endmodule
```

and adder module is

```
module ADD(fxw,As,Bs,Cs,Ds,Es);
    output  [41:0] fxw;
    input [41:0] As;
    input  [41:0] Bs;
    input  [41:0] Cs;
    input  [41:0] Ds;
    input  [41:0] Es;
 assign fxw=As+Bs+Cs+Ds+Es;   
endmodule
```

but in the simulation result in the same state s3,s4.s5,s6 the value of fxw and Fsx are the same but test is different

[simulation result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8208m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you dont provide all the details of exactly what the simulation results are and how they differ from what youd like, I can see that there is a major error in your code that is likely resulting in the unexpected behavior you are experiencing. You are mixing Non-blocking assignment (`<=`) and Blocking assignment (`=`) in a single clocked `always` block. I cant quite figure out what you are doing as some of your code is not shown, but if you want some things to behave combinationally, you should NOT put them in a clocked block. Separate your combinational logic from your registers, also be sure to understand what you want stored and what you want to result from combinational logic (note, I am just guessing with some of these, but some use blocking assignment when they should be registers using NBA):

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  case (p_s)
    ...
    s3: begin
      if (shifted2 < z) begin
        z <= z - shifted2; 

        // Note that As, Bs... are all dependent on fx which in turn is dependent on As, Bs... so one of these NEEDS to be stored in a register to break the combinational loop
        As <= fx;
        Bs <= fx >>> 1;
        Cs <= fx >>> 3;
        Ds <= fx >>> 6;
        Es <= fx >>> 7;

        // If you want Fsx and test to match, you must have them both update at the same time, before you had Fsx getting its value from the sum of the values of As, Bs... that were just generated while test would get the value from the sum of the previous values of As, Bs...
        Fsx <= fx;
        test <= fxw;
      end
      shifted2 <= shifted2 >>> 1;
      n_s <= s4; // You had 4, but I assume this should be s4
    end
    ...
  endcase
end

// Note, you could use an assign for this, but just to illustrate the point
always @(*) begin
  fx = 0; // Need a value for fx when state ISNT s3 or s4, this is combinational logic after all
  if ((p_s == s3) || (p_s == s4)) begin
    fx = As + Bs + Cs + Ds + Es;
  end
end
```

Comment: thank u very much for ur time; if i remove the combinantial adder the system work perfectly. i will update the code to the details.

Comment: I tried the always@(*) suggested but it did not work. i also tried to replace = with <= in always@(posedge clk) but it did not work again. I used `=` becouse i want my code to be excecuted one after each other not at same time. but even when i use `test=fxw` the value of `fx` and `test`  are not equal

Comment: yoy were right man!! the value of test was some of previous values of As,Bs, ... the problem solved by shifting the value of As,Bs,.. to the previous state outside of if loop.thank u very much and viva stackoverflow!

Comment: @elec_hi The issue is not really with just using `<=` or `=`, as in your case, the line `test = fwx` will run before the `assign` in the `ADD` module will see the updated `As`, `Bs`, etc. Thus, the value of `fwx` will be from the previous values of `As`, `Bs`, etc. Using NBA (which you should use in clocked blocks) will use the old value of `fwx`. Unless you use a combinational block, you cannot get the latest value of `fwx`. Understand that you are designing hardware, thus you need to describe your system to behave as such. If this is for a testbench, that changes alot of how you should code.

Comment: Also, I fixed a few things in my answer as I didnt quite get your logic right the first time :) (had a few things in the `if` that shouldnt have been)